# How to use subquery in select clause that joins to from clause subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I am trying to join a subquery to a from clause subquery. However, doing so causes the following error:

> SQL Error [208] [S0002]: Invalid object name 'transactions'

I am trying to rewrite multiple queries to fit them into 1 query because the query are almost identical, only a where clause is different.

Here is one of my attempts:

```
SELECT
    transactions.OpeningDateFormatted,
    (SELECT SUM(transactions.amount) 
     FROM transactions 
     WHERE transactions.transactiontypeid = 5) AS AdjustmentSum,
    (SELECT SUM(transactions.amount) 
     FROM transactions 
     WHERE transactions.transactiontypeid = 1) AS InterestSum
FROM  
    (SELECT
         FORMAT(files.OpeningDate, 'yyyy-MM') as OpeningDateFormatted,
         amount,
         transactiontypeid
     FROM
         FilesTransactions
     INNER JOIN
         files ON files.id = filestransactions.exid
     WHERE
         FilesTransactions.TransactionDate BETWEEN '2015-10-15' AND '2019-10-15' 
         AND ExID IN (SELECT id FROM files 
                      WHERE files.OpeningDate BETWEEN '2015-10-01' AND '2019-09-30' 
                        AND files.CustomerID = 3258)) transactions
GROUP BY
    transactions.OpeningDateFormatted
```

I have also tried to do the following but it gives me the same amount for every months:

```
select
FORMAT(files.OpeningDate, 'yyyy-MM') as OpeningDateFormatted,
(select sum(FilesTransactions.Amount) as CollectedSum from FilesTransactions f2 join FilesTransactions on FilesTransactions.id=f2.id where f2.transactiontypeid = 5 and FORMAT(f2.TransactionDate, 'yyyy-MM') like FORMAT(FilesTransactions.TransactionDate, 'yyyy-MM') )
FROM
    FilesTransactions
    inner join files on files.id = filestransactions.exid
where
FilesTransactions.TransactionDate between '2015-10-15' and '2019-10-15' and
ExID in 
    (
        select id from files where files.OpeningDate between '2015-10-15' and '2019-10-15' and files.CustomerID = 3258
    )
GROUP BY
FORMAT(FilesTransactions.TransactionDate, 'yyyy-MM'), FORMAT(files.OpeningDate, 'yyyy-MM')
```

What I'd like to have is one query that gives me the following

```
OpeningDateFormatted | AdjustmentSum | InterestSum
        2015-11             0               45
        2015-12             45.25           7
           ...               ...            ...
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic would all help.

Comment: use conditional aggregration instead of a subquery... `sum(Case when transactionTypeID = 1 then amount else 0 end) as InterestSum`

Comment: your first one validates OK on SSMS window - is it only failing when you run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using conditional aggregation and avoid the derived table entirely.

```
SELECT FORMAT(files.OpeningDate, 'yyyy-MM') as OpeningDateFormatted
     , SUM(CASE when transactiontypeid = 5 then amount else 0 end) AS AdjustmentSum
     , SUM(CASE when transactionTypeID = 1 then amount else 0 end) AS InterestSum
FROM FilesTransactions
INNER JOIN files 
   ON files.id = filestransactions.exid
WHERE FilesTransactions.TransactionDate BETWEEN '2015-10-15' AND '2019-10-15' 
  AND ExID IN (SELECT id 
               FROM files 
               WHERE files.OpeningDate BETWEEN '2015-10-01' AND '2019-09-30' 
                 AND files.CustomerID = 3258)) transactions
GROUP BY FORMAT(files.OpeningDate, 'yyyy-MM')

I might be more inclined to use an exists instead of an IN for exID...
```

or if you're really stuck on using the transactions table... use a Common table expression (CTE) ...

```
WITH Transactions as (SELECT
         FORMAT(files.OpeningDate, 'yyyy-MM') as OpeningDateFormatted,
         amount,
         transactiontypeid
     FROM
         FilesTransactions
     INNER JOIN
         files ON files.id = filestransactions.exid
     WHERE
         FilesTransactions.TransactionDate BETWEEN '2015-10-15' AND '2019-10-15' 
         AND ExID IN (SELECT id FROM files 
                      WHERE files.OpeningDate BETWEEN '2015-10-01' AND '2019-09-30' 
                        AND files.CustomerID = 3258)
SELECT transactions.OpeningDateFormatted,
    (SELECT SUM(transactions.amount) 
     FROM transactions 
     WHERE transactions.transactiontypeid = 5) AS AdjustmentSum,
    (SELECT SUM(transactions.amount) 
     FROM transactions 
     WHERE transactions.transactiontypeid = 1) AS InterestSum
FROM transactions
GROUP BY transactions.OpeningDateFormatted
```

Comment: Excellent, this is exactly what I needed. Thank's for the help, I had not thought of using conditional aggregation.